# Mongoose 'arrays of subdocuments' how not to make it appear in mongodb if not created

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using mongoose version 4.4.11.

I have created a `blog` document in mongodb with only `title` property (view the example below).

In my schema there is an other property `author` that is not present in mongodb. The same for `body` as a single nested subdocument that is not present in mongodb. I like this behaviour since it makes coding easier at the frontend.

I have `comments` as an arrays of subdocuments in my schema. Why is `comments` created with an empty array `[]` and is there a way not to make it appear in mongodb?

```
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title:  String,
  author: String,
  body: {
    text1: String,
    text2: String
  },
  comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }]
});

var blog = mongoose.model('blog', blogSchema);

blog.create(
  { "title": "test" }
)
```

Gives the result in mongodb:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5aa7d967423a0a1b1be62b70"),
  "title" : "test",
  "comments" : [],
  "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to remove the blank array? It is the design. It gives you the convenient way to push or pull from your model. You can check the length to make sure it has any value or not. 
If you do not want to display it in MongoDB. You can check at this link https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1335. Hope it helps